# Linux sed - Delete words do not start with a specific character

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

How to remove words that do not start with a specific character by `sed`?

Sample:

```
echo "--foo imhere -abc anotherone" | sed ...
```

Result must be;

```
"--foo -abc"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "--foo imhere -abc anotherone" |\
sed -e 's/^/ /g' -e 's/ [^-][^ ]*//g' -e 's/^ *//g'
```

The first and last -e commands are needed if only when the first word can be wrong either.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more the meaning of patterns? I will accept this solution as answer because it also works on BSD sed but can pattern be more simple?

Comment: Thanks. The middle pattern does the main work. It removes all substrings starting with space followed by the bad character until the end of the given word. Unfortunately it doesn't work if the whole string starts with a bad word, this is why I add an additional space to the beginning in the first pattern, and remove it in the last. I didn't find a way to spare the first/last steps, but in theory something like this could work: `'s/(^| *)[^-][^ ]*//g'`, but it needs some more tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

gnu sed with `-r`:

```
kent$ echo "--foo imhere -abc anotherone" | sed -r 's/^|\s[^-]\S*//g' 
--foo -abc
```

However I prefer awk to solve it, more straightforward:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=($i~/^-/?$i:"")}7'
```

output:

```
--foo  -abc
```

Comment: It doesn't remove the first "word" if it is wrong. `echo "xxx --foo imhere -abc anotherone" |...`

Comment: Is it possible to use the same pattern `'s/^|\s[^-]\S*//g'` with mac OSX sed? @LajosVeres Yes, you are right, also your solution also works in mac OSX.

Comment: @Sezen don't know the ERE option for bsd sed. as Lajos Veres commented, the sed line has problem if the first word not starting with `-`. `sed -r 's/(^|\s)[^-]\S*//g'` can quick fix, but still not perfect. I suggest you taking the awk one-liner, simple and easy to understand.

Comment: You `awk` would leave lots of extra space for the removed fields.  This `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/^-/) printf "%s ",$i;print ""}'` would solve that, except for last extra space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ssed` to enable PCRE regex and then you can use this one:

```
(?<!-)\b\w+
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/jJ1iC3/1)**

[image]

```
echo "--foo imhere -abc anotherone" | ssed 's/(?<!-)\b\w+//'
```