# Bash sed - find hashtags in string

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27197327/linux-sed-delete-words-do-not-start-with-a-specific-character), I have tried to come up with a command to find all hashtags words (words starting by #) in a quite complicated string:

```
echo "Le #cerveau d’#Einstein n’est « #Ordre des #Mopses\" » pas" | sed -e 's/^/ /g' -e 's/ [^#][^ ]*//g' -e 's/^ *//g'
```

Unfortunately the output is:

```
#cerveau #Mopses"
```

instead of:

```
#cerveau #Einstein #Ordre #Mopses
```

What should be the correct command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`grep` is usually better at extracting substrings. With the GNU-grep's `-o` option (only output the matching parts), you can just

```
echo "Le #cerveau d’#Einstein n’est « #Ordre des #Mopses\" » pas" \
| grep -o '#[[:alpha:]]*'
```

If you really need `sed`, do the similar thing: replace all words that don't start with a `#` by a space, then remove the first word and compact the spaces:

```
sed -e 's/[^[:alpha:]#][[:alpha:]]*/ /g' \
    -e 's/^[^#]*//' \
    -e 's/  */ /g'
```

Comment: You may want to replace the `[[:alpha:]]*` with `[[:alpha:]]\+` to prevent a single lone `#` to get matched.

Comment: @dani'SOlearnvaluenewbies': ✅ is not `[:alpha:]`.

Comment: The original question tried to output the hashtags, you're trying to output the value associated with them. Ask a new question.

Comment: This solution doesn't works for numbers, so if the input contains `#100`, the output is empty (no result/null). Same if it contain an emoji or any other special character. The more universal solution, thanks to @Aserre, is to replace `[[:alpha:]]*` (in the `grep -o '#[[:alpha:]]*'`) to `...\+`. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70219038/5623661)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `sed`, you can separate out all words that start by a `\n` and then find them:

```bash
echo "Le #cerveau d’#Einstein n’est « #Ordre des #Mopses\" » pas" \
| sed -re 's/(#\w+)/\n\1\n/g' \
| sed -rn '/^(#\w+)$/p'
```

You need the `-r` option in `sed` to use extended regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
echo "Le #cerveau d’#Einstein n’est « #Ordre des #Mopses\" » pas" | grep -o '#[a-zA-Z0-9_]\+'
```

You get the expected output:

```
#cerveau
#Einstein
#Ordre
#Mopses
```

Explanation: The `-o` option in grep:

> Prints only the matching part of the lines.

So, the `grep` command above matches a hashtag followed by a non-zero number of alphabets, digits and underscores.

Comment: `*` is equivalent to `{0,}` and also matches `#`. Your regex and your last statement are contradicting.

Comment: oh, you are right. when i try to fix it by simply changing the `*` at the end to `+`, the command returns nothing. in other words, `echo "Le #cerveau d’#Einstein n’est « #Ordre des #Mopses\" » # pas" | grep -o '#[a-zA-Z0-9_]+'` prints nothing, whereas the same thing works correctly in an online tester: https://regex101.com/r/zG3sP5/1 . This is weird.

Comment: You need to escape the `+` with a backslash.

Comment: oh, got it. editing the answer right away. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

One more kick at the can with a single command (substitution) and no regex extensions:

```
echo "Le #cerveau d’#Einstein n’est « #Ordre des #Mopses\" » pas"   \
| sed -e 's/[^#]*\(#[[:alpha:]]*\)[^#]*/\1 /g'
```

extracts words starting with a `#` and deleting all other strings.
Extraction relies on `sed`'s greedy `*` evaluation.

output:

```
#cerveau #Einstein #Ordre #Mopses
```

test environment:

```
linuxuser@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.15.0-74-generic #84-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 19 08:06:00 UTC 2019 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
linuxuser@ubuntu:~$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.4
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

---

aside, consider:

```
echo "# Le #cerveau d’#Einstein n’est « #Ordre des #Mopses\" » pas"  \
| sed   -e 's/[^#]*\(#[[:alpha:]]*\)[^#]*/\1 /g'

# #cerveau #Einstein #Ordre #Mopses
```